# Sitecore 9: Make 'full name' field searchable from user manager (Solr)

Tags: sitecore

Sitecore user accounts have an out-the-box field added to asp membership user profiles called 'Full name'. This field is not searchable from the user manager in Sitecore (See pic).

How do we make this field searchable?

[image: sitecore>users]

Comment: You have to create a computed field in (Solr ?) Since you are not mentioning what is your search provider, but probably Solr. You can take a look at this article : https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2021/04/26/sitecore-computedindexfield-extends-your-solr-index/.